# SQL number of grouped rows with conditional

Tags: php, sql

I am using the statement below to group results by month to give a total price however I also need to know how many rows have been grouped, but only if the price is above a certain amount.

```
"SELECT SUM(price) FROM table  GROUP BY month";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `COUNT` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(price), COUNT(CASE WHEN Price > 100 THEN 1 END)
FROM table
GROUP BY month
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98dcb0/1)

Answer (score 2):

use `SUM with CASE`

```
SELECT SUM(price) totalPrice, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN price > x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalRows  
FROM   table  
GROUP  BY month
```

where `X` is the value of price